# How to close an application in silverlight

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, silverlight-5.0, app.xaml

I am Silverlight beginner and Under a situation that i have to created the login pop up which lets the user go in further on entering the "Ok" button but i want the application to be closed on "Cancel" button click .

Actually this login pop up is a `ChildWindow`

I have tried both `Application.Current.MainWindow.Close();` and `Application.Current.Exit;` none of them work. **Could some one please help me in achieving my target.**

Comment: Probably an obvious question, but this isn't running in a browser, right?

Comment: Also what happens when this code is called? Does it just not close or is there an exception?

Comment: @Savanna yes it is not running in browser.

Comment: Check this SO question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255442/silverlight-out-of-browser-application-will-not-close-using-mainwindow-close-met It's possible that it's a permissions issue.

Comment: But it's solution of permission problem ? (because the answer there are not marked as answer)

Comment: Read the info there. It should give you an idea of what the problem could be. The question explains how to check your code to see if it is, in fact the same error that you are having.

Comment: If it's a "trust" issue, this should be helpful too. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721083(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: @Savanna I have an exception : Access to the property call or method is not permitted unless the application has elevated permissions or if the code was called through an action initiated by the user ON DOING : App.Current.MainWindow.Close();

Comment: So there you go. THat's your issue. Follow the second link and make your application install with elevated permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your application to require elevated trust when running outside the browser.

See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833073(v=vs.95).aspx

> To configure out-of-browser support In Solution Explorer, select the
>   Silverlight project for which you want to enable out-of-browser
>   support. On the Project menu, select project name Properties. On the
>   Silverlight tab, select Enable running application out of the browser.
>   Click Out-of-Browser Settings. The Out-of-Browser Settings dialog box
>   appears. Specify values for the indicated fields and then click OK.
>   All fields are optional except for the following: Window, Title,
>   Shortcut name, Application description

Set the SecuritySettings.ElevatedPermissions property to Required.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.securitysettings.elevatedpermissions(v=vs.95).aspx